# One Listener instace for all components or an instance for each component

Tags: java, swing

**Short Question**

I want to know if there is any good practice recommendation about write one listener instace for all components or an instance for each component.

**Extended Question**

I'm developing a java swing application.

In the same form i can have a dozen of components (with no relation between them) that use the same listener class. I write each of my listeners in their own class.

The listeners are used to make some validations over the data introduced on the component.

Should i create an instance of the listener class for each component, or should i use the same instance of the listener for all the components.

I can't find any good practice suggestion about this, except [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936261/how-to-add-action-listener-that-listens-to-multiple-buttons#comment6841109_5936261), that does not point to any reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the particular case of `ActionListener`, encapsulate the desired functionality using [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). The wide [use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/class-use/Action.html) of this class throughout Swing suggest its value. This simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513) illustrates a few built-in text component actions; this more elaborate [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) shows how actions can be shared among menus and toolbars.

The alternative is an ever-growing and hard-to-maintain `if-then-else` ladder based on the event source.

Addendum: Ah, I misread your question. @Andrew's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936261/how-to-add-action-listener-that-listens-to-multiple-buttons#comment6841109_5936261) is about *classes*; your question asks about *instances*. For the former, a single listener tends to evolve toward a a [known anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object); earlier versions of the [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) cited illustrate the problem. For the latter, use only as many instances as required; I usually catch the most egregious violations in a trip through the profiler.

Comment: +1. It's not the kind of answer i was looking for but i didn't know about "Action" and seems pretty interesting. Thanks

Comment: @FranciscoPuga: Thanks; I've elaborated above.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is the one that makes your code the cleanest possible.

Basically, if having one single instance doesn't complicate the code too much then you could create just one instance and share it across the components. Otherwise, you can have multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose one which keeps your code readable and maintainable.

If creating instances makes it simpler go ahead and do it but since the behavior remains the same; I believe single instance should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is really interesting........

Moveover if its Swing....then its already based on `MVC` architecture......

`Model` **-** Business Logic and Data

`View`  **-** Representation of Output

`Controller` **-** On which the action is done.

Now i think its also better to have the `Business Logic with its data together`, so we can easily associate the logic and its corresponding data.

You can always have an a **common listener** for **common EventSource**, like `JButton`...

You can have 4 `JButton`, which **do different works**, now you can have a single  `ActionListener` with `switch` statements..... quite easy to handle......