# Java Swing register to event type

Tags: java, swing

In Java Swing I can register a listener to a certain gui event as follows

```
guiElement.addMouseListener(myListener);
```

but what if I want to automatically register to all the mouse events in my GUI application?
should I register myListener to each element?
In other words what I am looking for is something like

```
myListener.registerToEventType(MouseEvent.class)
```

Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: *"register to all the mouse events"* Why such an interest in the mouse events?  Usually I'd side step a `MouseListener` for an `ActionListener`.

Comment: The MouseListener is just an example, the question applies to all the events type

Comment: **Why such an interest in the events?**  Add *more* words now, rather than less.  I don't like having to play '20 questions' to get basic information.

Comment: If you're really adventurous, take a look [Toolkit#addAWTEventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener(java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long))

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry for that. An example application could be to log all the mouse clicks in my application for analysis purposes. I may want to register to such type of events in one place instead of having a dedicated "logListener" everywhere manually registered to each gui element

Answer (score 3):

> but what if I want to automatically register to all the mouse events
>   in my GUI application?

@see AWTEventListener, there are Mouse & Key Events

> should I register myListener to each element?

yes is better than to redirect, consume or using SwingUtilities for apply MouseEvents to the derised JComponets, notice code could be longer than annonymous listener added to each of JComponents separatelly

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot do that, the way you want it. A possible approach is the use of **`Action Commands`**, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5937586/2148953).

```
JButton hello = new JButton("Hello");
hello.setActionCommand(Actions.HELLO.name());
hello.addActionListener(instance);
frame.add(hello);

JButton goodbye = new JButton("Goodbye");
goodbye.setActionCommand(Actions.GOODBYE.name());
goodbye.addActionListener(instance);
frame.add(goodbye);



 ...
  }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.HELLO.name()) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
   } 
else if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.GOODBYE.name()) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
   }
}
```

This is just an example, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
            System.out.println(mouseEvent.getPoint());
        }
    }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```